# Can admob banner ads be applied on Dialog? Or its against google ads placement policies

Tags: android, admob, adbannerview

I have custom dialog in my app, they popup when some event occur.
I am thinking to put banner ads on my app dialog popups.
Will that be a good practice ,or its against google banner ads placement policy ?

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same problem. You cannot use them in Dialog box as the ads wont appear.

Answer (score 1):

This could work (you can display an AdView in a PopupWindow, for example), but if the dialogs come up quickly and disappear quickly, it doesn't give the user much time to see and interact with the banner, which can lead to lower clickthrough rates and less revenue for you.

I'd recommend looking at our [Interstitial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) format. You could load them in advance, and display them when the user closes a dialog. If the dialogs are really frequent, you could only show an ad every fifth time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many games and apps that have ads on dialog boxes, so it's possible to do so.